# How to collect functions affected by specific optimizations in LLVM IR?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

In a module with several functions, I want to know what functions have been modified by a specific built-in pass without instrumenting it. I can, for instance diff the original and modified modules and see what functions are different, but this is too time consuming.

Using OPT, is there a programmatic way of determining what functions had their contents modified by a specific optimization pass in LLVM IR?

Can `opt` dump this information for me?

If not, is there anything on the `llvm::PassManager` that I could use to create such functionality?